# Create an html watermark text for an input that stays visible while a user enters text

Tags: jquery, html

I am building an application that allows a business to access their business via theirname.mydomain.com. I am building the signup form now to do this.

Anyway I came across squarespace today and their have a signup form that is actually like I want. if you browse to [squarespaces site](http://www.squarespace.com/) and click "try it free" they have their sign up form in a modal popup.

The popup looks like. the input box for username has a placeholder text of username.squarespace.com

When you start typing in a username the .squarespace.com is still visible.

How do I replicate this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Hiya is this what you want: I made this for you but I reckon got bit late let me know if you want me to chuck it as answer anyways :) http://jsfiddle.net/NXAWW/ , this will keep part of watermark in the text box like the sample in other page! have a good one, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya Setting up as answer if someone had same issue :) and for future reference as it seems to be that you might end up using the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/NXAWW/

This will keep part of watermark in the text box like the sample in other page! have a good one,

**Key is this**

```
.keyup(function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val().trim() != '') {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
        //$placeholder.val('');
    } else {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
    }
});
```

**Full Jquery Code**

```
// Create placeholder input to serve as background
var $test = $('#test');
var $placeholder = $test.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('placeholder').addClass('placeholder').val($test.attr('placeholder'));
var $container = $('<span class="placeholder-container"></span>');
$container.insertAfter($test).append($test).append($placeholder);

// Basic styling
$container.css({
   position: 'relative'
});
$test.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent'
});
$placeholder.css('color', 'transparent');

// Behavior for focus and blur to achieve the visual effect
$test.focus(function(){
   var $input = $(this);
   var $placeholder = $('.placeholder', $input.parent());
   $placeholder.css('color', '#e0e0e0');
}).blur(function(){
   var $input = $(this);
   var $placeholder = $('.placeholder', $input.parent());
   if ($input.val() == '')
       $placeholder.css('color', 'transparent');
}).keyup(function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val().trim() != '') {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
        //$placeholder.val('');
    } else {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
    }
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

They probably dynamically add .squarespace.com to the username as you type it.

You could try using **[onKeyUp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)** event to add text to your textbox as well like this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace('.hello.com', '') + '.hello.com'" />
```

Comment: Sorry Zathrus. One more question. Is it possible to have the cursor appear before .hello.com? it doesnt seem quite right having the cursor at the end

Comment: well, my answer does not handle cursor position nor am I able to say if it's possible... but see @Tats_innit's comment, which seems to work with a positioned SPAN element

Answer (score 0):

When you type your username the initial text-overlay is replaced by a second which gets dynamically positioned as you type. Just add an `onkeyup` event handler which calculates the width of the current inputted text and position the overlay accordingly.

The `css` of the site isn't quite wonderful though, see what happens as you type a larger username:

[image: Create your website]

But this can be easily resolved by adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent element.

Comment: haha good spotting jb10210. Maybe they assume nobody will create a user account that long :)