# Placeholder remains visible on focus

Tags: javascript, css, html, placeholder

I'd like my `<input>` elements to have placeholder text which remains visible when the input has focus (and is empty).  However, I can't use the actual `placeholder` attribute, since it only shows up in IE10 and Safari when the input does not have focus, and is not supported in older IE versions.  What is a cross-browser solution, preferably not using jquery (since I have no other reason to use it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery here is an option

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/FdjJv/8/

```
$(function()
{
  $('input').each(function() 
  {
     $(this).val($(this).attr('holder'));
  });

  $('input').focus(function()
  {
    if($(this).attr('holder')==$(this).val())
    {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });
  $('input').focusout(function()
  {
     if($.trim($(this).val())=='')
     {
       var holder = $(this).attr('holder');
       $(this).val(holder);
     }
  });
});
```

For full browser support you can use a library such as http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

**EDITED**

I would recommend a jQuery plugin and then you can assign it to your inputs

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5j55m/136/

```
<input type='text' placeholder='this is a test' />
<input type='password' placeholder='testing password' />
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the text visible on focus.

Comment: won't that confuse the user? it would be like two words on top of each other miss aligned!?

Comment: No, it's only when the input box doesn't have text typed into it.  This is the default behaviour in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Comment: I see what you mean - Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution using jQuery.. http://jsfiddle.net/NXAWW/

---

[Create an html watermark text for an input that stays visible while a user enters text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042122/create-an-html-watermark-text-for-an-input-that-stays-visible-while-a-user-enter) :

**Key is this**

```
.keyup(function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val().trim() != '') {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
        //$placeholder.val('');
    } else {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
    }
});
```

**Full Jquery Code**

```
// Create placeholder input to serve as background
var $test = $('#test');
var $placeholder = $test.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('placeholder').addClass('placeholder').val($test.attr('placeholder'));
var $container = $('<span class="placeholder-container"></span>');
$container.insertAfter($test).append($test).append($placeholder);

// Basic styling
$container.css({
   position: 'relative'
});
$test.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'transparent'
});
$placeholder.css('color', 'transparent');

// Behavior for focus and blur to achieve the visual effect
$test.focus(function(){
   var $input = $(this);
   var $placeholder = $('.placeholder', $input.parent());
   $placeholder.css('color', '#e0e0e0');
}).blur(function(){
   var $input = $(this);
   var $placeholder = $('.placeholder', $input.parent());
   if ($input.val() == '')
       $placeholder.css('color', 'transparent');
}).keyup(function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val().trim() != '') {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
        //$placeholder.val('');
    } else {
        $placeholder.val($input.val().trim() + $input.attr('placeholder').replace('test',''));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the find!  I'll see if anyone can suggest a solution using plain Javascript.